# CSS3 IE9 Support

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I'm trying to make a Jagged Edge border without using an image and I'd like to still support IE9 and up. Is this possible? As of right now it works in everything but IE9. Any advise would be great! Thanks so much.

Here is my code that I'm using.

```
<div class='demo'></div>


/* Jagged Edge */
 div {
    background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #fff 10px, transparent 0) 0 10px, linear-gradient(135deg, #fff 10px, #333 0) 0 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-size: 20px 20px;

    /* otherwise these will be overridden when you add the inline styles with js. */
    background-position: left bottom !important;
    background-repeat: repeat-x !important;

    padding:1em;
    width:100%;
 }
```

Here is a jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/26uW4/1/

I thought about using a data-uri with a SVG. Thoughts on that? I'm unsure how to pull that off.

Comment: Why no images?  Couldn't you use a data-uri with a `png`?

Comment: Was trying to do it without an image but I don't think its possible given linear-gradient is not supported in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

As far as a `data-uri` svg, put this in your CSS:

```
background:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
```

I got that string by drawing the path in Adobe Illustrator, exporting as a SVG, base64 encoding the svg, and inserting it in a `data:image/svg+xml`.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/26uW4/2/) for a working demo.

Comment: You think that would be better or this...? progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#333', endColorstr='#333',GradientType=1 )

Comment: Interesting.  I've never heard of that `progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient` thing.

Comment: Okay. I'll test both and see what renders... I'm waiting for a PC to test on. Thanks so much for the info!